# Does AWS SDK JS v3 no longer support hardcoding credentials in React Native Apps?

Tags: react-native, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-js

I am creating a React Native app that involves sending some kind of information to AWS using AWS Simple Notification Service (SNS). This is a one-way operation that the device publishes some string to a specific topic.
However, the AWS manager provided me an `access_key_id`, `secret_access_key`, and the ARN of that topic to publish.
I don't know how to encode the these credentials into my app using aws-sdk-js V3 ([@aws-sdk/client-sns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-sns)).

I have verified that the credentials work in AWS Python SDK (`boto3`).
I tried two methods from credential providers (@aws-sdk/credential-providers): Shared INI files and Environment variables. However, they don't seem to work as warnings raised when installing the debug application to a real Android device.

I understand that it is **dangerous** to hardcode the credentials into the code directly, but my application would be only used for a **private demo**. **My manager wants it to work in a hurry**.

I would also like to know what is the preferred way to get authenticated, so I can suggest to the AWS manager and replace those in future.

Answer (score 0):

import either *SERVICE_NAME*Client or *SERVICE_NAME* class from the package and initialize it with *credentials*.

```
import { SNS } from '@aws-sdk/client-sns'

const sns = new SNS({
 credentials: {
  accessKeyId: *YOUR_AWS_KEY_ID*,
  secretAccessKey: *YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY*
 },
 region: *eg. us-east-1*
})
const response = await sns.SOME_OPERATION({})
```

You can find more config here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-middleware-signing/Interface/AwsAuthInputConfig/